# How to make this button, clickable in touch devices?

Tags: html, css, menu, responsive-design

I have a problem with menu button. I found this code in the net and the button is with label & input. It is not clickable in touch devices like phones. How can I do this button clickable?

Please help somebody

Here is the link: http://jsfiddle.net/Ltspckd0/

**HTML Code**

```
<div id="adminmenu">
    <label for="show-menu" class="show-menu">Menuja</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="show-menu" role="button">
    <ul id="menu">
        <li><a id="ahome" href="#">Kreu</a></li>
        <li><a id="apatients" href="#">Pacient</a></li>
        <li><a id="advisit"href="#">Vizita</a></li>
        <li><a id="areports"href="#">Raporte</a></li>
        <li><a id="aprofile"href="#"><?php echo $username=user_name(); ?></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS Code**

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#adminmenu li {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    border-right: 1px solid #F5F5F5;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    min-width: 140px;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    background: #2D6CA2;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li:hover a {
    background: #428BCA;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li:hover ul a {
    background: #f3f3f3;
    color: #2D6CA2;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
}

li:hover ul a:hover {
    background: #428BCA;
    color: #fff;
}

li ul {
    display: none;
}

li ul li {
    display: block;
    float: none;
}

li ul li a {
    width: auto;
    min-width: 100px;
    padding: 0 20px;
}

ul li a:hover + .hidden, .hidden:hover {
    display: block;
}

.show-menu {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    background: #428BCA;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px 0;
    display: none;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
    display: none;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ #menu {
    display: block;
}

@media screen and (max-width : 760px) {

    ul {
        position: static;
        display: none;
    }

    li {
        margin-bottom: 1px;
    }

    #adminmenu ul li, li a {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .show-menu {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using jQuery mobiles tap event? http://api.jquerymobile.com/tap/ it mimics click behaviour on mobile devices

Comment: I would just use javascript. I see you've been creative with CSS to achieve this somewhat hacky clicking system, but certain browsers on mobile will try to render checkboxes differently than on PC by making them touch-friendly for use in forms (since that's their main use). Almost all browsers today support javascript, and almost everybody has it enabled (regardless of what they say)

Comment: And the biggest problem is that he just copy/pasted the code, so he hasn't been creative at all :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add jQuery click/tap event to the menu like this

```
$('.show-menu').on('click tap', function(e){
    $('#menu').toggle();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Since the OP was trying to use pure CSS (which I don't think really will work well here), he/she obviously wants things to be quite lightweight. Perhaps an answer without jQuery could be better?

Comment: He is not saying that he wants it all in css. He is asking how to make the button clickable on phones. So this is how :)

Comment: yeah. I was just thinking it could be faster on mobile as well, since jQuery's quite a bulky library and lots of mobile users are on a slow connection when there's no wifi, so pure javascript or a smaller, more focused library would probably be better. I just somehow don't like it when people use jQuery for the smallest things: http://www.doxdesk.com/img/updates/20091116-so-large.gif

Comment: I know what you mean. But when I write in vanilla javaScript lots of times people don't know what's going on. Simply nowadays everybody is used to jQuery and nothing else.

Comment: this solution works perfectly but meny stay open, how to make it close after pressed?
Thanks again @BojanPetkovski

Comment: If you add this code you don't need the input field anymore. Example here http://jsfiddle.net/Ltspckd0/3/ On click on Menuja you can toggle opened and closed state :)